# (Fullcalendar 4 VueJs) columnHeaderHtml - how to show (dayName, dayNumber) like (Mon, 8), (Tue, 9) etc

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In column header for Week Mode i need to show (dayName, dayNumber) format. I use "columnHeaderHtml" method for this but i don't know **how to get the proper dayNumber**.

To show dayName i use this:

```
columnHeaderHtml(date){
   return `<span>
             ${date.toLocaleDateString('default', { weekday: 'short' })} 
          </span>`;
   }
```

Please give some advice,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [columnHeaderFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat) option instead, you can do something similar quite easily:

```
columnHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric' }
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abbejWK

---

Alternatively, if you need a bit more flexibility, then you can continue to use the `columnHeaderHtml` option, and just append the day number on to the string as follows:

```
columnHeaderHtml(date) {
      return `<span>
             ${date.toLocaleDateString("default", { weekday: "short" })}, ${date.getDate()}
          </span>`;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/QWWeBPq

Comment: Thank you ADyson for the response. This approach is not very flexible for me because i need "DayName" goes first.  With columnHeaderFormat It always goes "DayNumber" and "DayName"....

Comment: I see. Try my second suggestion then (check the updated answer)

Comment: No problem. You can find all the functions for getting data from a JS Date object here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date